# Should there be a V6 Specific Powershell Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Version 6 of Powershell is significantly different from every prior version. Unless I am completely missing it there is not currently a V6 specific tag. I believe that there should be one. The adoption at first I suspect will be spotty and often wrong, but as more people start using V6 I believe that it will be helpful.

Comment: There are already specific version tags. See the following: [tag:powershell-5.0], [tag:powershell-4.0], [tag:powershell-3.0]

Comment: There is no V6 tag yet.  You can't just create a tag, it needs to be associated with at least one question.  I checked for existing Powershell questions and found only one so far that contained a reference to V6: https://superuser.com/questions/1320481/powershell-6-missing-cmdlets.  You can create one on that question or wait for the next V6 question and add it there.  At least one more question needs to be tagged within 6 months or the tag turns into a pumpkin.

Comment: I looked for a v6 tag on a question I just asked (https://superuser.com/questions/1324007/setting-window-size-and-position-in-powershell-5-and-6), didn't find one, and was going to ask on meta, when I found this. I don't have the rep yet to create tags. @EBGreen can you create it now?

Comment: I've created the powershell-6.0 tag.

Comment: We may wish to synonimize [tag:powershell-core] and [tag:powershell-v6.0] as they currently refer to the same thing. Though I suppose, depending on what happens with PowerShell 7, that may need to be reversed eventually.